# Building a string from two Boolean values

Tags: scala, boolean

I have two boolean values, `b1` and `b2`, and I want to make a string from them like this:

```
--> str = "b1"     # if b1 is true and b2 is false
--> str = "b2"     # if b2 is true and b1 is false
--> str = "b1, b2" # if both are true
--> str = ""       # if both are false
```

What's the simplest way I can write it in Scala?

Here's my first attempt:

```
val b1str: String = if(b1) "b1" else ""
val b2str: String = if(b2) "b2" else ""
val str = List(b1str, b2str).mkString(",")
```

That is ugly and does not even work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that generalizes to more than two elements:

```
List(b1, b2)
    .zip(Stream from 1 map ("b" + _))
    .collect({ case (true, s) => s })
    .mkString(",")
```

But if what you're doing doesn't truly match that abstraction, it might be more appropriate to just use a pattern match to enumerate all four cases:

```
(b1, b2) match {
    case (true,  true)  => "b1,b2"
    case (true,  false) => "b1"
    case (false, true)  => "b2"
    case (false, false) => ""
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very general since I'd bet the poster was using "b1" and "b2" as placeholders just to demonstrate the desired behavior...

Comment: Ah, I didn't read it that way - but I've updated my answer to include that possibility. And I'm going to update it to use `collect` as your answer does...

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
List((b1,"b1"), (b2,"b2")).collect { case (b,s) if b => s }.mkString(",")
```

Comment: `List((b1,"b1"), (b2,"b2")).collect { case (true,s) => s }.mkString(",")`

Comment: So, it works, but it's anything but obvious what it does. @ChrisMartin's match is probably the clearest (to me, anyway)

Comment: Well, I've updated my answer because I prefer the use of `collect`, so you probably like mine less now too :|

Comment: Yep :) Not getting at you (or dhg) specifically just having a general whinge about the "clever" solutions. I think the original intent has been obsured. I'm as guilty as anyone of these kind of solutions. As Rob Pike said more than 25 years agoin "The Elements of Programming Style": "Say what you mean, simply and directly." and "Write clearly - don't be too clever.". Hmnmm, I seem to have omitted to take my anti-curmudgeon pills this morning...

Comment: @Paul, I don't there's anything "clever" about my code: it's an extremely simple use of a common method from the scala standard library.  `collect` is just like `map` but only outputs the elements that pass the `if b` test.  That's it.  And it happens to be a perfect fit for the problem at hand: `map` over a collection while removing stuff that doesn't fit the criteria.

Comment: I also find @ChrisMartin's `match` statement the most readable code. Kernighan and Plauger [got it right](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~zs/comp20006_2011_s2/resources/style.pdf). `collect`-`case`-over-`List`-of-pairs is probably a Scala idiom I should get used to, but it still seems to me to hide in abstraction what the `match` makes plain. And then again, I indulged my enjoyment of cleverness in my answer below.

Comment: @Ben.  Hmm, I find the match version to be overly wordy, and weirder than "filter out falses, print the rest".  But the bigger issue is that it's totally not scalable since the number of case statements increases *exponentially* with the number of arguments.

Comment: @dhg, I know what collect does. It's still overkill here (all in my opinion of course), partly because you have to put them into a list in order to run collect on it If the OP had asked for something scalable to many items, I would have a different opinion.

Comment: @dhg, Indeed the `match` version would get unwieldy with more variables. But _when there are only two variables,_ the `match` version is as clear and straightforward as can be. I see a lot of code made hard to read by solving a more-general problem than the actual problem. Well, the OP now has lots to choose from to suit whatever his or her problem really is (note generalized possessive pronoun). @Paul, :)

Comment: Evaluating which solution is best requires predicting the way in which it is likely to be changed in the future.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Nooooooo! That way lies madness. We're well into the realm of opinion here, but many years of painful experience have taught that the simplest code for the present problem is not only the simplest code for the present problem, it's the best way to prepare for future changes (which usually don't happen as predicted, anyway).

Comment: Well, for all I know, maybe OP already has a dozen elements in mind, and just simplified it to two for the sake of the question.

Comment: Please please please explain your code to the readers. Throwing some code around without explanation is not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a sane approach. Whatever you do, don't vote this up. It does work, though. It works for any number of Boolean variables, you don't have to repeat the names of the variables in string literals, it handles arbitrary Boolean expressions as well as variables, and the calling code is extremely readable.

Here's a macro, `commaSeparatedTrueExprs`. Put this in a separate file:

```
// requires Scala 2.11
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
import language.experimental.macros

object commaSeparatedTrueExprs {
  def apply(exprs: Any*): String = macro impl

  def impl(c: Context)(exprs: c.Tree*) = { import c.universe._
    val elems = exprs map { expr =>
      val s = showCode(expr)
      q"if ($expr) Some($s) else None"
    }
    q"""Seq(..$elems).flatten.mkString(", ")"""
  }
}
```

Then this calling code:

```
for (b1 <- Seq(false, true); b2 <- Seq(false, true))
  println(commaSeparatedTrueExprs(b1, b2))
```

produces this output:

```
 
b2
b1
b1, b2
```

Here's calling code that illustrates passing arbitrary expressions to `commaSeparatedTrueExprs`:

```
val b1 = true
val b2 = false
println(commaSeparatedTrueExprs(b1, b2, b1 && b2, b1 || b2, true, false))
```

The output is:

```
b1, b1.||(b2), true
```

Comment: I don't know, I could sort of see the value of this for a logging framework or something?

Comment: Hmm, good point. I was thinking it was a bad idea to expose Scala variable names and expressions to the end user, but that's exactly what you'd want in a logger.

Comment: Now write a version using string interpolation!

Answer (score 0):

The following approaches extract those strings whose associated predicate evaluates to true; such strings are then appended.

Let

```
val a = List( (true,"b1"), (false,"b2"), (true,"b3") )
```

Then a similar (equivalent) approach to collecting,

```
a.view.filter( _._1 ).map( _._2 ).mkString(",")
res: String = b1,b3
```

or with a for comprehension

```
val b = for ( (b,v) <- a if b ) yield v
b: List[String] = List(b1, b3)

b.mkString(",")
res: String = b1,b3
```